# NSURLSession - The request timed out

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession

I'm posting data from my app to my server using NSURLSession when a button is pressed. I can successfully send the data to my server and insert into a database, for the first two occasions, but any time after that, the request times out.

I've tried: changing session configuration (connections per host, timeoutInterval etc), session configuration types, changing the way the data is posted.

Has anyone seen this sort of behaviour before and know how I can fix this issue?

Or is it a server issue? I thought my server was down initially. I couldn't connect to it, nor load certain pages. However, it was only down for me. After rebooting my modem, I could connect back to the server. I didn't have any issues connecting to phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Show.Your.Code.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem was reproducible after a reboot of the router, then I would look into whether Apple's captive portal test servers were down at the time.

Otherwise, my suspicion is that it is a network problem rather than anything specific to your app.

- It is quite possible that the pages you were loading successfully were coming from cache.
- Because you said that rebooting your modem fixed the problem, that likely means that your modem stopped responding to either DHCP requests or DNS lookups (either for your domain or for one of the captive portal test domains).
- It is also possible that you have a packet loss problem, and that it gets worse the longer your router has been up and running.  This could cause some requests to complete and others to fail.
- Occasionally, I've seen weird behavior vaguely similar to this when ICMP is getting blocked too aggressively.
- I've also seen this when a stateful firewall loses its mind and forgets the state.
- This can also be caused by keeping HTTP/HTTPS connections alive past the point at which the server gives up and drops the connection, if your firewall is blocking the packet that tells you that the connection was closed by the remote end.

But without a packet trace, there's no way to be certain.  To get one:

- If your network code is running on OS X, you can just do this with tcpdump on your network interface.
- If you are doing this on iOS, you can do this by connecting your computer via wired Ethernet, enabling network sharing over Wi-Fi, pointing tcpdump at the bridge interface, and pointing your iPhone at that Wi-Fi network.

Either way, that will tell you if there are requests going out that never come back, and more importantly, what type of requests they are, and who is responsible for replying to them.  Once you have that information, if the source of the problem isn't obvious, post a link to the packet trace and we'll add more suggestions.